# Enable Java Assertions for Debug APKs and Devices

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am asking specifically about enabling java assertions in the newest version of Android Studio with the Gradle build tools.  The linter recommends using them when it detects potential NullPointerExceptions so surely it is possible.

The following code works and throws an exception when a bug occurs:

```
if (vehicleLocation == null) throw new IllegalStateException("vehicleLocation is null");
```

This doesn't throw an AssertionError so I am assuming they aren't turned on.

```
assert vehicleLocation != null;
```

Comment: Do you mean assert null != vehicleLocation?

Comment: Consider placing your answer here.